# I want when no filters are selected then return all the data with the count

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, mysql-error-1064, case-statement

I'm creating a store which would run according to selected filter for example when studentid is passed then it will return all the data with count of records. When schoolid is passess then it will return all the data wrt to schoolid and count of records. Similarly i want when none of the filter is selected then return all the data with count of records. Currently it is showing **error** "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT
map.idnstudent as Student_Count,ma' at line 21". 
Please help me on this i need help big time. I've tried all possible solution till now.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TestspPendingTab_filter_all123`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TestspPendingTab_filter_all123`(IN `no_filter_data` VARCHAR(500), IN `search_keyword` VARCHAR(50), IN `Stud_id_filter` VARCHAR(100), IN `sch_id_filter` VARCHAR(100), IN `Subj_id_filter` VARCHAR(100), IN `start_date_filter` DATE, IN `end_date_filter` DATE, OUT `recordfound` INT(10))
BEGIN

CASE WHEN no_filter_data = 'YES' THEN
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT
map.idnstudent as Student_Count,map.idnstudent as student_id,usr.name as student_name,
map.idnsubject as Subject_Count,map.idnsubject as subject_id,sn.sub_name as subject_name,
s.id as School_Count,s.id as school_id,ifnull(s.schoolname,'N/A') AS schoolname
from `user` `usr` 
join `student_class_hour_map` `map` on `map`.`idnstudent`=`usr`.`id` and `usr`.`flag_status`=1
left join `subject_name` `sn` on `sn`.`id` = `map`.`idnsubject` 
left join `school_student_rel` `ssrl` on `ssrl`.`student_id`=`map`.`idnstudent` 
left join `school` `s` on `s`.`id` = `ssrl`.`school_id` 
WHERE 1
AND map.archivestatus=0 
AND recordfound = FOUND_ROWS()

ELSE 

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT
map.idnstudent as Student_Count,map.idnstudent as student_id,usr.name as student_name,
map.idnsubject as Subject_Count,map.idnsubject as subject_id,sn.sub_name as subject_name,
s.id as School_Count,s.id as school_id,ifnull(s.schoolname,'N/A') AS schoolname    
from `user` `usr` 
join `student_class_hour_map` `map` on `map`.`idnstudent`=`usr`.`id` and `usr`.`flag_status`=1
left join `subject_name` `sn` on `sn`.`id` = `map`.`idnsubject` 
left join `school_student_rel` `ssrl` on `ssrl`.`student_id`=`map`.`idnstudent` 
left join `school` `s` on `s`.`id` = `ssrl`.`school_id` 

WHERE 1
AND map.archivestatus=0 
AND
CASE WHEN search_keyword != '' THEN
 (s.schoolname like CONCAT('%', search_keyword, '%') OR sn.sub_name like CONCAT('%', search_keyword, '%') OR usr.name like CONCAT('%', search_keyword, '%'))
ELSE
 1 
END  
AND
CASE WHEN Stud_id_filter != '' THEN
FIND_IN_SET(map.idnstudent,Stud_id_filter)
ELSE 1
END

AND 
CASE 
WHEN sch_id_filter != '' THEN
FIND_IN_SET(s.id,sch_id_filter)
ELSE
1
END 

AND 
CASE 
WHEN Subj_id_filter != '' THEN
FIND_IN_SET(map.idnsubject,Subj_id_filter)
ELSE
1
END

AND 
CASE 
WHEN start_date_filter != '' AND end_date_filter != '' THEN
map.startdate >= start_date_filter and map.enddate <= end_date_filter

ELSE
1
END
END

GROUP BY 
CASE WHEN stud_id_filter <> '' THEN map.idnstudent END,
CASE WHEN sch_id_filter <> '' THEN s.id END,
CASE WHEN subj_id_filter <> '' THEN map.idnsubject END;
SET recordfound = FOUND_ROWS();

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Expected output : It should return all the data with count of records when none of the filter is selected. If any filter is selected then return data according to that filter with count of records.

Comment: This kind of stuff is better done in the application.  Namely, construct the desired query, then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

In stored-procedure code of the form

```
CASE
WHEN something
THEN query1;
ELSE query2;
```

you need semicolons after the queries. You don't have them.

Your code is a little confusing because you're using `CASE` both for control flow and as SELECT logic.  It's the control flow that needs semicolons/

Comment: Thanks you so much  O.Jones for the revert, now for outer condition i'm using IF statement THEN - ELSE END IF; Which is running fine and data

Comment: Thanks you so much  @O.Jones for the revert, now for outer condition i'm using             
IF statement THEN - ELSE END IF; Which is running fine. But now problem is when any filter is selected it is returning data wrt to that particular filter with record count which means else part is giving absolutely right output but when no filter is selected or when value passed to parameter(no_filter_data= 'yes') then it is returning recordcount =0. Instead of 0 it should return all the data with record count.

Comment: @RohitSwamy share the updated script by editing your post.